# Does the following curve have positive curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I am asked the following question.  Give a closed plane curve $C$ with $\kappa>0$ that is not convex. I think I have an answer but I am unsure of the positive curvature portion of the question. The curve is closed and it is not convex but I am not sure if it has positive curvature

[image]

Comment: Intuitively, if the 2D curve "turns" both left and right as you follow it, then the curvature must have changed signs. Maybe the [limaçon trisectrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on_trisectrix) is a better example?

Comment: Do we know this curve has positive curvature?

Comment: Looking at the picture on the Wikipedia page, it is clear that the curvature is either always positive or always negative. If it happens to be negative, a very simple idea would be to "run the curve in the other direction" by replacing $t$ by $-t$ in the parametric formula, which I trust, would give you a curve with positive curvature this time.

Comment: Looking at the normal vectors on the “outside” of the shape, it seems to have positive curvature on the “loops” and approaches zero curvature near its self intersection. If we follow the drawing of the shape just like how one would draw an 8 without lifting their pen, would give negative curvature on the “inside” outline of the figure. However,  I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm just noticing now that your problem statement mentions $\kappa$, which is typically used to denote *unsigned* curvature. So it's not so much about the sign, but the $\kappa > 0$ requirement is about the curve never having inflection points, e.g. not allowed to turn in the other direction. In which case, my original suggestion would seem to adequately fit the bill.

Comment: Thank you! I think that the limacon trisectrix is a good option for the question

Comment: You should specify here. Are you talking about *signed* curvature? And your curve certainly has points with $\kappa=0$. Using signed curvature, this curve is roughly half positive curvature and half negative curvature, by the way.

Comment: Yes I am talking about signed curvature. I guess my confusion is what it means for a curve to have positive curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on what was said in the comments: if we consider a limaçon trisectrix curve like
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 1+\cos(t)+\cos(2t) \\
y = 1+\sin(t)+\sin(2t)
\end{cases}
$$
then the sign of its curvature is the sign of [$x'y''-y'x''$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization), which in this case corresponds to

$$
(-\sin(t)-4\sin(2t))(-\sin(t)-2\sin(2t))-(-\cos(t)-4\cos(2t))(\cos(t)+2\cos(2t)) \\
\begin{aligned}
&= \quad \sin^2(t)+8\sin^2(2t)+4\sin(t)\sin(2t)+2\sin(t)\sin(2t) \\
&\quad +\cos^2(t)+8\cos^2(2t)+4\cos(t)\cos(2t)+2\cos(t)\cos(2t) \\
&= 1+8+6(\sin(t)\sin(2t)+\cos(t)\cos(2t)) \\
&= 9 + 6 \cos(t)
\end{aligned}
$$
which is evidently always strictly positive.

Comment: It's quite clear geometrically that the acceleration vector is always pointing inward. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin clearly, I just thought that presenting a result supported by some algebra would help convince the OP, as (s)he seems most anxious about the (strict) positivity of the curvature.

Comment: The point, I think, is for the OP to understand what signed curvature means geometrically. :)

Comment: I believe I did try to address that point in the comments of the question, pointing out that it was unclear whether the problem statement was about signed or unsigned curvatures. I'm just noticing now the exchange you had with the OP on that topic. I'm not sure why the OP didn't react to my own prompting.